# How to get the list-objects using a folder name within the bucket

Tags: shell, prefix

how to get the list of objects using s3api list-object using the foldername inside the bucket 
for ex: I have the key as below
`/my-bucket/look-map/email/jan2018/look-map-highlights.csv`

I searched as below using s3api and didn't get any objects listed.

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket   --prefix look-map/email   --query 'Contents[].[Key,Size,LastModified]' --output text`

please let me know do we any option to get the object based on the prefix /look-map/email

Comment: As I need to get the objects only present in the /look-map/email folders

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive ls as following

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/look-map/email --recursive
```